# how to capture the job status in shell script for spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sh, airflow

I am using bashshell with spark-sql-2.4.1v.
I submit my spark job using spark-submit in a shell script.

```
Need to capture the status of my job. how can this be achieved ?
```

Anyhelp/advice please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below code.

```
process_start_datetime=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
log_path="<log_dir>"
log_file="${log_path}/${app_name}_${process_start_datetime}.log"

spark-submit \
    --verbose \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --executor-cores "$executor_cores" \
    --num-executors "$num_executors" \
    --driver-memory "$driver_memory" \
    --executor-memory "$executor_memory"  \
    --master yarn \
    --class main.App "$appJar" 2>&1 | tee -a "$log_file"

status=$(grep "final status:" < "$log_file" | cut -d ":" -f2 | tail -1 | awk '$1=$1')
```

**To get Application Id**

```
applicationId=$(grep "tracking URL" < "$log_file" | head -n 1 | cut -d "/" -f5)
```

Comment: sir what is this 2>&1 | tee -a "$log_file" ??

Comment: so what is 2 here ?

Comment: echo $LOG_PATH  gives blank , so can i set this current dir ?

Comment: yes, you have set dir before execution. for above question check this - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections

Comment: what this --- cut -d ":" -f2 |  -- do  here ?

Comment: cut will split the fields, -d will be delimiter & -f will be the field in reverse order

Comment: , one more doubt what is this  awk '$1=$1' ...what does mean here ?

Comment: trimming additional spaces something like - echo " Running " | awk '$1=$1'

Comment: any advice how to solve this in spark ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62933135/dataframe-look-up-and-optimization

Answer (score 1):

`spark-submit` is a async job, so when we submit the command you can get the application id by Calling `SparkContext.applicationId`. You can then check the status.

reference-https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5439

if spark is deployed on Yarn then you can check the status using-

```scala
///To get application ID use yarn application -list
yarn application -status application_1459542433815_0002
```

There is another way they mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232872/4758823)

Comment: how to get this applicationId inside the shell script ?..which invokes spark-submit